# Don't show div surrounding a yield if nothing calls it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this snippet in a layout:

```
    <div class="yui-g" style="min-width: 760px">    
      <!-- top row -->  
        <%= yield :top_row %>
    </div>
```

If nothing calls `content_for :top_row` then i'm left with a styled, empty rectangle on the page.  The right thing to do would be restyle the layout (and the whole site tbh) but that's not an option right now (legacy debt and more pressing requirements).  Is there a way to wrap the div in some code that checks if the yield is actually yielding to anything, and to not render it if so?

cheers, max

EDIT - this is a rails 2.2.2 project btw.

EDIT 2

@arnep suggested the following, which works:

```
<% content = yield :top_row %>
<% unless content.blank? %>
  <div class="yui-g" style="min-width: 760px">   
    <%= content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What i'd like to do next is to wrap that up in a helper which i can use like so:

```
<% yield_if(:top_row) do |content| %>
  <div class="yui-g" style="min-width: 760px">   
      <%= content %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm struggling with that helper though, since it involves yielding in the block passed to the method AND yielding to the content in :top_row.  Here's what i tried, which doesn't work - it renders the whole page into the returned string.  I think i've got it backwards somehow.

```
def yield_if(content_name, &block)
  content = yield content_name 
  if content.blank?  
    ""
  else
    yield content 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [2.2.2 `content_for`](http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M002176&name=content_for) and it uses `instant_variable_set` for this. May be you can use [`instance_variable_defined?`](http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M000095&name=instance_variable_defined?) to query for your `:top_row` content.

Another idea could be to assign the content to a variable `<% content = yield(:top_row) %>` and then use `content.present?` to circumvent an empty `div`.

Comment: Thanks @arnep, that works!  I'm now trying to wrap that up in a method , see edit in original post.  Can you see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: `yield content` seems a bit strange to me as `content` already contains the yielded content. If `content = yield content_name` does not work try `content = yield content_name.to_sym`. Try `logger` to get some output of your variables into your log files.

Comment: yield content_name works, as content_name is being passed a symbol such as :top_row, but it renders too much into the content variable - from the doctype (in the head) down to the end of what it should be doing.  This is based on logging the content variable contents.  The odd thing is that if i then return content, instead of `yield content`, it just says "top_row".  The confusion for me comes from the fact that i'm yielding twice: once to the containing snippet of html, and once to the larger chunk (eg :top_row) passed in a content_for block in one of the templates.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, there is a [content_for?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F) helper just for that of checking.

Comment: Hmm, not in this project's version of rails (2.2.2), unfortunately (Sorry, should have listed the version in my post).  I looked at copying the source into my own version of the helper, but it refers to a variable @view_flow, which i don't have and haven't seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've no access to `content_for?`,  the only way to go through this seems to use javascript and remove the div if it's empty.